# How to do in-page jumping while using Django for pulling posts from a database

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to create jump links within a page that are placed on a sidebar using `<a href>` tags as shown [here](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/link-within-a-page.shtml).

However, since I am using Django for pulling in different posts from a database, I have to use a `for loop`. Because of it, I can not use anchor tags. Is there any way to implement them using Django for loops?

```
  <body>
    <div class="sidenav">
  <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/">Login</a>
  <a href="#Plant_Kingdom">Plant Kingdom</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
        <div>
            <h1><a href="/">Nayan's Files Online!</a></h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div>

                <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                <p><b>published: {{ post.published_date }}</b></p>
                <h4><p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p></h4></div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body></body>

</html>
```

For [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjGCE.jpg): when the user clicks plant kingdom he should jump to the heading plant kingdom.

How can anchor tags be done inside a for loop?

Comment: thanks for the edits @julian and kindly forgive my mistakes if any i'm a newbie.

Comment: you are welcome. It is a pleasure to do it. You do not need to apologise. All learn from the mistakes and this is the first step to learn: ask without fearing to make mistakes.